# how to display an element only on mobile view?

Tags: html, css, email, eloqua

Im creating an email template on Eloqua, so what i have successfully did was hide an image when on mobile view. So it shows only on desktop view. Now im trying to do is to view another image only on mobile view and not on desktop view. How can i achieve this? Pls take a look at my code

```css
@media (max-width: 480px) {
.size-controller {
  width: 100%;
}
.mobile-16px-font {
  font-size: 16px !important;
}
.mobile-hide {
  display: none !important;
}

.mobile-show {
  
}
.mobile-100-percent {
  width: 100% !important;
}
}
```

```html
<br> <span style="font-size: 20px; color: #26478D;">April 30 Web event, 4.30-5.00pm</span>

                                         <img src="http://images.go.experian.com/EloquaImages/clients/ExperianInformationSolutionsInc/%7B2fd05069-3482-4a59-a8ee-b60f8b8c2c5e%7D_macbook-pro-3030365_300.jpg" width="250" align="right" class="mobile-hide" hspace="10">

                                         <img src="http://images.go.experian.com/EloquaImages/clients/ExperianInformationSolutionsInc/%7B2fd05069-3482-4a59-a8ee-b60f8b8c2c5e%7D_macbook-pro-3030365_300.jpg" width="250" align="right" class="mobile-show" hspace="10">

                                         <br><span style="font-size: 14px; color: rgb(87, 87, 85); border-style: none; padding-right: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-top: 10px;" class="mobile-16px-font">
                                    
                                    We did have something a bit more elaborate than a web event planned for April, however we’re equally excited to see how we go! We’ll be holding it at 4.30pm (EST) on April the 30th. <br><br>

                                          Tune in to hear more about how Experian has adjusted their way of doing business over the last couple of months, the latest features available in Aperture 2.0 and hear directly from a couple of our Advocates on how they have benefited from the Advocate program, and how they have adapted to the new norm.<br><br>
We’ll run the event via a Webex, all you will need to do is grab a drink and click this link a few minutes before the time;   <a href="https://oneexperian.webex.com/oneexperian/onstage/g.php?MTID=e3f8dd6ff4b183fc082b93cab47892e3f&elqTrackId=dde80b180c2f4e0d9ea2b393afa99c17&elqTrack=true" align="center" data-targettype="link" title="Link">Webex event – 30 April at 4.30pm</a></span><div class=""><br>
```

I cant seem to be able to show the image only on mobile view and not desktop view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a similar logic to hide the `.mobile-show` image. Instead of using `max-width: 480px`, you can use `min-width: 480px` to only apply the show `.mobile-hide` on a viewport larger or equal to `480px`.

Although unrelated to your case, I have concerns on your CSS and HTML. You shouldn't use [`!important` carelessly](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity). You should wrap text node in a HTML tag and heading should be wrapped with the heading tag (e.g. `<h1>`). Furthermore, in your case, it's better to use a CSS class than inline styles.

```css
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .size-controller {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .mobile-16px-font {
    font-size: 16px !important;
  }
  .mobile-hide {
    display: none;
  }
  .mobile-100-percent {
    width: 100% !important;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 480px) {
  .mobile-hide {
    display: inline;
  }
  .mobile-show {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1 style="font-size: 20px; color: #26478D;">April 30 Web event, 4.30-5.00pm</h1>

<p>
  <img src="http://images.go.experian.com/EloquaImages/clients/ExperianInformationSolutionsInc/%7B2fd05069-3482-4a59-a8ee-b60f8b8c2c5e%7D_macbook-pro-3030365_300.jpg" width="250" align="right" class="mobile-hide" hspace="10">
  <img src="http://images.go.experian.com/EloquaImages/clients/ExperianInformationSolutionsInc/%7B2fd05069-3482-4a59-a8ee-b60f8b8c2c5e%7D_macbook-pro-3030365_300.jpg" width="250" align="right" class="mobile-show" hspace="10">
  <span style="font-size: 14px; color: rgb(87, 87, 85); border-style: none; padding-right: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-top: 10px;" class="mobile-16px-font">
                                    
  We did have something a bit more elaborate than a web event planned for April, however we’re equally excited to see how we go! We’ll be holding it at 4.30pm (EST) on April the 30th.<br>
  Tune in to hear more about how Experian has adjusted their way of doing business over the last couple of months, the latest features available in Aperture 2.0 and hear directly from a couple of our Advocates on how they have benefited from the Advocate program, and how they have adapted to the new norm.<br><br>
  We’ll run the event via a Webex, all you will need to do is grab a drink and click this link a few minutes before the time;   <a href="https://oneexperian.webex.com/oneexperian/onstage/g.php?MTID=e3f8dd6ff4b183fc082b93cab47892e3f&elqTrackId=dde80b180c2f4e0d9ea2b393afa99c17&elqTrack=true" align="center" data-targettype="link" title="Link">Webex event – 30 April at 4.30pm</a></span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use combination of `@media` with `max-width` and `min-width`.

- Use `min-width` to show or hide the block **above** some break point. in
  this example i am using `480px`. you can change as per your
  requirement.
- Use `max-width` to show or hide the block **below** your breakpoint.

run the snippet in full screen and try to resize the window down below to `480px` and you will see the result.

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .show-on-desktop {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 481px) {
  .hide-on-desktop {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
   <div class="show-on-desktop hide-on-mobile">
      <h1>This is for desktop</h1>   
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350" alt="" />
   </div>
   
   <div class="show-on-mobile hide-on-desktop">
     <h2>This is for mobile</h2>
     <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250" alt="" />
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Zuber. Why did you add hide-on-mobila and show-on-mobile in both divs even though you do not have it defined in the css?

Comment: Hi @AnaSustic, I added these classes so the questioner can easily understand the solution i provided. Besides that, It is for readability so that in future, you or other developer can understand the responsive behaviour of the element. You can remove those classes but i'll recommend you to use them because You can change the behaviour for responsive using `@media` using those classes. Let me know if you have any further query.